# Wrong focus sequence when hiding element on keydown event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, events, focus

I have the following markup http://jsfiddle.net/tpveo23c/1/:

```js
var onKeydown = function() {
  document.getElementById('testDiv').style.display = "none";
};
```

```html
<input type="text" value="1" onkeydown="onKeydown();" />
<div id="testDiv" style="width:300px; height:50px; border:1px solid black">
  <input type="text" value="2" />
  <input type="text" value="2" />
</div>
<input type="text" value="3" />
```

There is a problem with focus on Tab in Firefox. 
Steps to reproduce: focus on input1 -> press tab.
Expected behavior: focus on input3 (Chrome / IE works fine).

I don't know how many inputs in testDiv, and can't focus input3 manually.
How to make it work in Firefox as in Chrome/IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```js
var onKeydown = function() {
  document.getElementById('testDiv').style.display = "none";
  var width = document.getElementById('testDiv').offsetWidth;
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tpveo23c/2/